# Drupal: How to make a fieldset dependent using CTools

Tags: drupal, drupal-ctools

I am using Ctools Dependency to make a fieldset hideable. This is part of my code:

```
$form['profile-status'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' => '',
    '#options' => array(
        'new' => t('Create a new profile.'),
        'select' => t('Use an existing profile.'),
    ),
);

$form['select'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Select a profile'),
    '#options' => $options,
    '#process' => array('ctools_dependent_process'),
    '#dependency' => array('radio:profile-status' => array('select')),
);

$form['profile-properties'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('View the profile'),
    '#process' => array('ctools_dependent_process'),
    '#dependency' => array('radio:profile-status' => array('select')),
    '#input' => true,
);
```

In snippet above, There are two elements, one select and one fieldset. Both have #process and #dependency parameters and both point to one field for dependent value. Problem is elements like select or textfield can be hidden easily but it does not work for fieldset. In [this](http://drupal.org/node/654218) support request page, CTools creator has mentioned that `'#input' => true` is a work around. As you see I added it to code, but it does not work as well.

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found my answer after reading the source of CTools dependent. Fieldset should change as this:

```
$form['profile-properties'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('View the profile'),
    '#process' => array('ctools_dependent_process'),
    '#dependency' => array('radio:profile-status' => array('select')),
    '#input' => true,

    '#id' => 'my-fs-id',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="my-fs-id-wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
);
```

First an ID must be set for he fieldset. Then it must be wrapped in a DIV tag. ID of the DIV should be feildset's ID suffixed with '-wrapper'.

Answer (score 1):

now (Feb 2013) usage is:

```
$form['foo_or_bar'] = array(
    '#title' => 'Foo or Bar',
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#options' => array(
        "foo" => "Foo",
        "bar" => "Bar"
    ),
    '#default_value' => "foo",
);

$form['react_on_foo'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Foo fieldset'),
    '#dependency' => array('radio:foo_or_bar' => array('foo')),
);

$form['react_on_foo']['dummy_for_foo_fieldset'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Dummy for FOO fieldset'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
);


$form['react_on_bar'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Bar fieldset'),
    '#dependency' => array('radio:foo_or_bar' => array('bar')),
);

$form['react_on_bar']['dummy_for_bar_fieldset'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Dummy for BAR fieldset'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
);
```

And #process is no more needed.